Loop through resources and combine info of each resource with 2 other lists
Terraform newbie here.
I have the following code (filenames and descriptions are comma separated input strings)
locals {
  files = split(",", "${var.filenames}")
  descs = split(",", "${var.descriptions}")
}

data "local_file" "p_files" {
  for_each = toset(local.files)
    filename = "../${each.key}.json"
}

I would like to loop through the p_files and create a policy for each. In incorrect syntax something like
resource "aws_organizations_policy" "org_policies" {
   for_each = local.p_files
     name = "get name from local.files"
     content = ${each.value}.content
     description = "get description from local.descs"
}

I believe I need somehow to combine the 3 data structures local.files, local.descs and p_files into one using flatten and then loop through that structure to create the policies.
I am not sure what the syntax would be to create that structure and how to then loop through it.

locals {
  files = split(",", var.filenames)
  descs = split(",", var.descriptions)

  file_desc_map = { for idx, file in local.files : file => local.descs[idx] }
}

data "local_file" "p_files" {
  for_each = toset(local.files)
  filename = "../${each.key}.json"
}

resource "aws_organizations_policy" "org_policies" {
  for_each = data.local_file.p_files

  name        = each.key
  content     = each.value.content
  description = local.file_desc_map[each.key]
}


Why is each.key the same as the value in local.files? (data.local_file.p_files doesnt have any name)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
